PCA applied to non-linear data
Assume I apply standard principal component analysis to data, where the observed variables are non-linear functions of factors. That is I have a panel variable $Y_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{N_{Y}} $, which can be represented $Y_{i}=g(X_i)$ for factors $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^{N_{X}}$ and $N_{X} < N_Y$. Is there some literature on such problems? Is there e.g. some Gauss-Markov type result, so that the $N$ first principal components give the best linear $N$-factor approximation?

Do you know the functions in question, at least their functional form?

@jbowman Not really. You can impose some regularity conditions and an answer in some special case might also be helpful.
